# Can we specify External image source in Sitecore Image Field

Tags: sitecore-client

Is it possible to specify an external image source for a Sitecore Image Field?

So that an author can also visualize it in the content editor and not need to store in Sitecore media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible out of the box.

Sitecore `Image Field` allows to select image from `Media library` item only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We have some requirement where client want to add external image reference. As Sitecore is Web CMS and image Preview is also possible as we provide preview for internal image, RTE preview .

We will develop custom filed that will allow to add external image source like Sitecore provide for general link and they will be able to preview the image in Content editor itself.